# How to build a udp connection with python server and universal robot simulation software as a client?

Tags: python, udp, robotics

I am working with universal robot 3 simulation software and want to control the virtual robot created in the universal robot simulation software by using an external python server. I have modified the code from the universal robot's website for establishing a client server connection but getting an error which states that

```
send value from server is not a number
```

and in the python console for `c.send` command I get warning stating

```
expected bytes instead of str
```

I would really appreciate if you guys can look int o the following code and suggest me any way to fix the error. Please feel free to point out any error that you may find in the code as I new with python and networking. Thank you all in advance.

I have tried instead of `c.send`, `c.sendall()` and also tried to use `c.send(bytearray[200,50,25])` but still in the client side, I get errors stating that `send number is not a number`. Please suggest me how to fix the error so that after the client and server communication is established, I can send these three values to the universal robot simulation software and can alter the position of the simulated robot.

```
 import socket
 import time
 HOST = "192.168.0.100"  # The remote host
 PORT = 30000  # The same port as used by the server
 print ("Starting Program")
 count = 0

while (count < 1000):

 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
 s.bind((HOST, PORT)) # Bind to the port 
 s.listen(5) # Now wait for client connection.
 c, addr = s.accept() # Establish connection with client.

 try:
  msg = c.recv(1024)
  print ("msg")
  time.sleep(1)
  if msg == "asking_for_data":
      count = count + 1
      print ("The count is:", count)
      time.sleep(0.5)
      print ("")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      c.send("(100,50,25)");
      print ("Send 100, 50, 25")

except socket.error as socketerror:
print ("count")

   c.close()
   s.close()

   print ("Program finish")
```

Comment: [`send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) expects a `byte` object, so just send one instead of a `str` object: `c.send(b"(100,50,425)")`  However it's unclear where you are getting the other error unless you can specify it in your question.  Post the full traceback.

Comment: Thank you @Idlehands for your suggestion.I already tried the code that you suggested, I get an error stating b is not defined. As for the error that I get which says that send value is not a number, I get this error in the universal robot simulation software where I open the same port and ip address and store the value send from the server into a variable and in the variable I get NAN values when I run the server and client.I feel it has something to do with the c.send command in the python server

Comment: Hi, everytime I try to run the program where c.send(“(100,50,25)”) says
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:/Users/Scorpio/Desktop/serverClient.py”, line 29, in
c.send(“(100,50,25)”);
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not ‘str’

Comment: Yes, because you are supposed to send a `byte` object.  Though I'm unsure why you get an error `b is not defined`?? Please post the traceback with the updated error on `c.send(b"(100,50,425)")` because Python should recognize `b` prefix as a `byte` object.  As for your other error it depends on what format your software is looking for.  Is it expecting 3 separate numbers? A `tuple`-like object that gets parsed as a coordinate? Make sure you pass in a `byte` object with format that matches what the software expects.

Comment: Thank you IdleHands.I left my laptop at a friends place which has the client program and can get it on Monday but I clearly remember getting an error stating b is not defined.Since I use ubuntu virtual box to work with the universal robot simulation software, I tried the python code in ubuntu and I am not sure whether the b is not defined error is because of version issue of python or not.

Comment: This is the example I am trying to implement http://www.zacobria.com/universal-robots-knowledge-base-tech-support-forum-hints-tips/knowledge-base/script-client-server/

Comment: It's most likely a typo because there's no reason you should get `b is not defined` if it was typed in exactly as I mentioned.  You might encounter other errors but that definitely should not be one of them.  A `str` with `b` prefix makes it a `byte` object and is understood by the python interpreter.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment.I will try it again on I get hold of my laptop.But can this be a python version error?Or maybe I had a typo.I will give you updates when I get to try again.Other than the byte command is there any other way to solve the original problem which said send value is not a number?Thanks in advance

Comment: I also wanted to clarify one other thing besides the major error that I am getting.I am new to networking so this might be novice but i am asking anyway, I have my python server and my client script in linux virtual machine.Is it possible to run the server from my windows machine and the client script being in the linux VM?